# Multiple Followups

Tags: scheduling, activity

I'm looking for a way to add multiple followups to an activity. I don't want people to have to go back into the activity and enter re-enter a new followup if possible. Rather, I was thinking of something like the Save + New Option that is present in other parts of the database.
So far I looked at custom data to see if there were options I could modify but I'm still puzzled. If anyone has even the faintest of an idea I would really appreciate because it would at least give me somewhere to start.

Thanks a ton,
V

Comment: Hi Vito, sorry I can't advise on this, but I think the 'scheduled reminder' tag you have used might mislead since i think most times that is related to these civicrm/admin/scheduleReminders?reset=1 whereas you are dealing with "Schedule Follow-up Activity"

Comment: Could you possibly modify the "CiviCases" add on?

Comment: I was also going to suggest that CiviCase might be a better fit, but it also adds complexity in a number of ways, and I think Vito's 'Save and New Option' seems like a valid and useful improvement if anyone can make it happen,

Comment: Oops- you're right petednz. I removed the offending tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, not saying that this would completely cover your need...

If you install the new extension CiviRules, you have several automatic options.

I can imagine that you set up a rule like this:

- **Event:** Activity is changed
- **Condition:** Field value comparison for a certain field you have updated
- **Action (option A):** Create activity with a certain activity type, activity title, activity status and assignee contact. (Then it can turn up in a to do-list)
- **Action (option B):** install the Email API extension as well, and have the option to send a email directly to the assignee containing a template with contact info(tokens). (This is described [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5118/how-to-notify-ceo-of-large-contributions)

So, instead of creating a separate Save and New option, you could have CiviRules automatically create the activity when you add certain values to the activity