# How to notify CEO of large contributions?

Tags: civirules

How can you make an automatical notification to your CEO every time a contact donates more than 10 000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install the extensions CiviRules and Email API.

- Then you could set up a rule, which triggers on contribution added.
- The condition should be contribution total amount larger then 10 000.
- And then the action should be "send mail".
- There you have the possibility to select a template. If you have created a template containing tokens of contribution details (you can easily use the extension Summary Fields to have the appropriate contribution tokens), then you can use that specifically for this purpose.
- And then  finally you can tick off a box to send the email to someone else than the contact itself. There you can write the email adress of your CEO.

Then your CEO will receive an automatical email containing the details (tokens) of the contact contributing more than 10.000

Comment: have you done this? if so which version of civi? I note civirules is only listed as tested for 4.4

Comment: Yes, I have this up and running in our production site. CiviCRM 4.4, yes:-)